# sending variable from index.html to app.component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

Can i send a variable from index.html to app.component.ts
i have this script in index.html and i want to send url which is variable before removing query params to app.component.ts

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = window.location.toString();
       if(url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
          var sanitizedUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
          window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, sanitizedUrl);
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. I made a small [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybjnbn) to show you how.

1. All you have to do is wrap your code as you did in index.html.
2. You have to declare the variable. You can do it inside the component as

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// notice that foo is inited in index.html
declare var foo;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
```

or in `typings.d.ts`. I recommend declaring it in typings.d.ts. If you're using angular-cli, and i assume, it is located in `src/app/typings.d.ts`.

```
declare var foo: any;
```

And that's it. You can use your variable anywhere in the app.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer and upvoting. Thanks @Fariba

Comment: you saw in my code i want to remove query params  from the url but i want to tell to app.component.ts that the url is the with query params,

Comment: in my app.component.ts i am using ActivatedRoute, to pars url, how can i pass this url to that?

Comment: ActivatedRoute is just an interface. If you want to do the redirection, I would suggest using router.navigate([url]) for it. Check more about that on [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router). Inject Router Service through DI, and call this.router.navigate() method in you class OnInit or constructor... depends. I would also consider using APP_INITIALIZER token for this.

Comment: i do not want to do redirection, i have a website and when other frontend want to load my website they send afew query params, i want to hid query params from my address bar

Comment: use Router for navigation and add an extra parameter to it. You won't have page reload and it will this.router.navigate([url], { skipLocationChange: true }). It won't have any refresh or sort like this and should do navigation without pushing the new state to history.

Comment: Thank you so much, i do not know how to do that, i do not know where can i deleter those query that others sent to my website, and i do not know how to use navigate, can you please look this my question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621788/removing-url-in-index-html-but-how-can-i-have-them-in-app-component-ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195024/discussion-between-fariba-and-nikola-stekovic).

Answer (score 0):

Inside .html file -->

```
<script>
   const baseUrl = "http://0.0.0.0/";
</script>
```

in .ts file just declare the variable and use it -->

```
declare var baseUrl;
export const BASE_URL = baseUrl;
```