# removing url in index.html but how can i have them in app.component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

I removed query params from url in index.html, but i want in app.component.html work with those query params, and my app.component.ts using ActivatedRoute,
Now when i have this script in index.html then my app.componen.ts also does not receive those queru params, how can i let app.component.ts have my query params?

this is my script in my index.html to remove query params:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.toString();
   if(url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
      var sanitizedUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, sanitizedUrl);
    }
  </script>
```

and this is my app.component.ts to pars query params:

```
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Converter} from './converter';
import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  username = '';
  department = '';

   json;
  constructor(
    private feedbackService: ApiService,
    private titleService: Title,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty('username')) {
        this.username = params['username'];
      }     
      if (params.hasOwnProperty('department')) {
        this.department = params['department'];
      }     
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not just place those query parameters into session storage and then access session storage inside app.component.ts?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.toString();
   if(url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
      var [ sanitizedUrl, queryParams ] = url.split('?')
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, sanitizedUrl);
      sessionStorage.setItem('params', queryParams)
    }
  </script>
```

```
//app.component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  username = '';
  department = '';

   json;
  constructor(
    private feedbackService: ApiService,
    private titleService: Title,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let params = sessionStorage.getItem('params');
    // parse params logic here // 

    if (params.hasOwnProperty('username')) {
        this.username = params['username'];
      }     
      if (params.hasOwnProperty('department')) {
        this.department = params['department'];
      }     

    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, there's no clear cut solution for it but still, I did manage to create some solution that should work.

Idea behind it in order to make it works is to keep query params in service.

Make a service that will hold the data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleService {
  data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
  data$: Observable<any> = this.data.asObservable();
}
```

afterwards, in your `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private sampleService: SampleService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sampleService.data$.subscribe(console.log);
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data: {username: string, departure: string}) => {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty('username') || data.hasOwnProperty('departure')) {
        this.sampleService.data.next(data);
      }
      setTimeout(() => { // note this timeout is mandatory and it makes this kinda cheatfix the whole thing
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      });
    });
  }
```

in this way, you'll have your params kept in SampleService's data behaviour subject. If you want to use it somewhere, all you have to do is inject service, and subscribe to `data$`.

Please note, this solution contains few subscriptions that should be handled carefully but not this question's topic.

Small short demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8s1y3). Check demo console when you open stackblitz app with queryParams as /?username=foo.